# golf statistics in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I this this is a very simple answer to a simple problem but I cant work this out. In my golf stats the cell contents in row 1 are the par of the hole, and row 2 has my score for each of the holes.
I have two rows of numbers and I want to compare the data in each column:
eg:

```
row 1 cell a1 is 4, b1 is 3, c1 is 4, d1 is 4, e1 is 5
row 2 cell a2 is 5, b2 is 3, c2 is 3, d2 is 5, e2 is 7
```

so translated this means that the par of the holes are 
`4, 3, 4, 4, 5`
and the scores I got on these holes was:
`5, 3, 3, 4, 7`

the answers I want to get is as follows (in different cells):

- how many times any score in row 2 is one less than any score in row 1,
- how many times any score in row 1 is equal or the same as any score in row 2,
- how many times any score in row 2 is one more than any score in row 1,
- how many times any score in row 2 is two more than any score in row 1 etc etc

I want excel to count the number of times each argument occurs and count them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

The formulas are

- A4 `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$E$1-$A$2:$E$2=1))`
- A5 `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$E$1=$A$2:$E$2))` I don't quite know if you make a difference between "equal" and "the same", but for me it's synonymous.
- A6 `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$E$2-$A$1:$E$1=1))`
- A7 `=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$E$2-$A$1:$E$1>1))`

I've used conditional formatting and a legend to highlight which cells belong to which count.

Does that help?

Comment: Hello Teylyn, you are so wonderful, it worked in my worksheet. It calculated my birdies, pars, bogeys and dbl bogeys. Thanks again, I would not have figured this out without your help. I had not thought of these formulas, I was thinking of IF and COUNTIF functions